# VBA for changing border line color in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Please help. I want a vba code through which I can change the border line color (0,51,141). Please note that I don't want a code for applying border to cell. I just need to change the line color so that I can apply borders the way I want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: seems to me a quick google search would give you sample code on how to do that.  Have you tried any of them?  If so please [edit] your post to include what you tried and explain where it fails.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to change the color of the cell :

```
Sub changeColorOnly()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("B20:X45")

    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Borders.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
    Next cell

End Sub
```

And change the parameters in **RGB** to  change the color.

Otherwise, adapt the range as you need.

Edit: After your comment.

```
Sub BorderDemo()
  With Range("A1:Z30")
    .BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
  End With

End Sub
```

And change the ColorIndex as you need :

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not looking for changing color. I just need to change the color of the border line for all future purpose.